# Custom font not loading in react direflow application

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, font-face

I have created a javascript direflow application. I am trying to load a local font but haven't been able to.

Below are the details and code snippets I have applied.

**Folder Structure**
[image]

**font.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyLocalFont';
    src: local('MyLocalFont'),
         url('./fonts/MyLocalFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./fonts/MyLocalFont.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

**direflow-components/testing-component/index.js**

```
plugins: [
    {
      name: 'font-loader',
      options: {
        custom: {
          families: ['MyLocalFont'],
          urls: ['/fonts.css']
        },
      },
    },
  ],
```

**App.css**

```
.header-title {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #5781C2;
  font-family: 'MyLocalFont';
}
```

The font files doesn't load. Please help.

Note: Built a react app using create-react-app there with @font-face changes the fonts load. Something with direflow is not working.

Comment: try create a build and then try again, sometimes the files don't get copied to your assets and as a result they don't get served.

Comment: There is no need to serve font files in .eot anymore, unless you're aiming for some backward compatibility of extreme level (https://caniuse.com/?search=eot). Also, in your css, you are referencing your woff2 file as if it was .woff and not .woff2

Comment: @Capagris Thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected the WOFF file and font name but still, I don't see the fonts loading.

Comment: Try using `file-loader` instead.

Comment: @dhruwlalan no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue seems like the plugin `font-loader` is not required. I removed it from `direflow-components/testing-component/index.js`.

Another change I made is removed the single quotes from the `font-family`.

**App.css**

```
.header-title {
    font-family: MyLocalFont;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Darshna Rekha, This doesn't seem to be working for me.
The fonts are not even bundling in production build of direflow. Could you please help or provide code sample that you have?

Comment: Consider this is the path for the fonts for me `testing-component/src/direflow-components/testing-component/fonts/Caveat-Bold.woff`, I have added the `font-face` in `testing-component/src/direflow-components/testing-component/App.css` at the top of the page.